# How to keep original dates after uploading to Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I am uploading several files to Alfresco repsitory via webdav. The batch process works fine, but after the upload, all dates in the repository are changed to current date.

How can I make it keep and show the original file dates (creation and modified) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage metadata extractors. The main purpose is to extract metadata from binary files during upload. There are lots of built-in metadata extractors, just look for implementers of interface `org.alfresco.repo.content.metadata.MetadataExtracter`. There are different extractors that can extract creation date and set it as `cm:created` on Alfresco node.

You can enable metadata extraction by applying it as a rule on a space, look for action named `Extract Common Metadata` in the actions drop-down-box while creating the rule.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible without the importing code explicitly turning off the default behaviour of the "cm:auditable" policy, and I suspect the WebDAV driver doesn't do this (since it has no way of knowing whether that's appropriate or not - there are cases where forcing the creation and modification dates to today is the correct thing to do).

This behaviour is discussed in some detail [here](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-bulk-filesystem-import/issues/detail?id=4) - it might be worth evaluating whether the bulk filesystem import tool is a more appropriate way to import the content into Alfresco, particularly since it can preserve the creation and modification dates if you tell it to (i.e. by specifying the values of those properties).